# iPad cursor jumps(displaces) in textareas

Tags: javascript, css, ipad, textarea

I am checking my application in Ipad having iOs 5.1
When i tap in textarea the cursor jumps two line above the writing line.
Tough the focus is on the right place but visual appearance of cursor is coming two lines above the line of focus .
any suggestions regarding this .

[This is CSS file code](http://tinypaste.com/0b49c264)

[This is HTML part taken from firebug not from file(you can see tag names)](http://tinypaste.com/96df1c87)
[video to show problem(video is not made by me , but problem is similar)](http://tinypic.com/r/20k6338/7)

Comment: code u wrote is expected here!

Answer (score 0):

iPad likely has some offset on the `touch` event, which you can cancel out with a function like this:

```
$('#yourTextarea').on('touchstart', function (event) {
    event.preventDefault(); //should prevent the hop
    // rest of your code goes here
});
```

Comment: this is not helping. when i am taping in text area ,it is not even showing cursor after using the above method